# Can't change the preferredTransform of the AVAssetTrack

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I tried to add a filter to each frame of the video, represented by `AVAsset`. However, when I added the filter using `AVMutableVideoComposition`, the orientation of the video changes. For example, the video was shot in a portrait, and after the filter is applied, the new video became landscape. I tried to print out the `preferredTransform` from two different tracks, one maintains its orientation after applying the filter, one rotates. The `preferredTransform` of the correct track will print out the identity matrix, which is `CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)`, and the one which rotates will print out something like `CGAffineTransform(a: 0.0, b: 1.0, c: -1.0, d: 0.0, tx: 1080.0, ty: 0.0)`. My intuition tells me that I might be able to reset the preferredTransform of the incorrect track. I tried to use the AVMutableVideoCompsitionLayerInstruction, but it does not work, and the video stop playing with no filter applied. Here is how I did it:

```
func addFilter(){
    if let asset = self.asset{
         let filterString =  "CIPhotoEffectInstant"
         let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
         let filtered = request.sourceImage.applyingFilter(filterString, withInputParameters: nil)
                    request.finish(with: filtered, context: nil)
                })
          guard let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first else {
                    return
          }
          print(CGAffineTransform.identity)

          //AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction
          let compositionLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
               compositionLayerInstruction.setTransform(.identity, at: asset.duration)


           //AVMutable​Video​Composition​Instruction
           let compositionInstruction =     AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
           compositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [compositionLayerInstruction]
            composition.instructions = [compositionInstruction]

            print(videoTrack.preferredTransform)
            self.playerItem?.videoComposition = composition

            self.currentVideoComposition = composition

        }
    }
```